# sorting of store goods

Tags: python, django, sorting, filter

I'm using ListView in my Class Based Views and I want to sort the goods by the selected field by the user, but I couldn't find the information I needed

*view*

```
class Shop(ListView):
    template_name = 'essense/shop.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 9
    allow_empty = False

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        ***context***

        return context

    def get_ordering(self):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('orderby',)
        print(ordering)
        return ordering
```

*template*

```
<form action="{% url 'shop' %}" method="get" id="sortProduct">
    <div class="product-sorting d-flex">
    <p>Sort by:</p>
        <select type="submit" name="select">
            <option type="submit" name="orderby" value="price">Price: $$ - $</option>
            <option type="submit" name="orderby" value="-price">Price: $ - $$</option>
                 </select>
                 <input type="submit" class="d-none" value="">
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* override the `get_queryset`, since there is where the ordering logic is happening. You can specify the model with the [**`model`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.model):

```
class Shop(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'essense/shop.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 9
    allow_empty = False

    # no get_queryset

    def get_ordering(self):
        return self.request.GET.get('orderby',)
```

or if you want to filter the queryset by making a super call:

```
class Shop(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'essense/shop.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 9
    allow_empty = False

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).all()

    def get_ordering(self):
        return self.request.GET.get('orderby',)
```

Note that it is not very safe to let a user select an arbitrary order by. Hashed passwords can be retrieved if one for example orders on `user__password` for example. Usually it is better to retain a list of fields that are allowed to order by.

Comment: Isn't it worth giving the user the opportunity to choose the display of the items he needs?

Comment: @boldRichard: yes, but not by introducing a (severe) security leak.

Comment: it works , but when i changed <option> to <input>, it looks horrible)

Comment: @boldRichard: why do you change `<option>` to `<input>`?

Comment: idk, i'm trying to smth , i've been sitting for 3 hours with this stuff, when the <option> nothing happens when i choose any, with <input> for some reason it works

Comment: @boldRichard: you should define the `name="orderby"` in the `<select>`, so `<select name="orderby">`, and the `<option>`s then have a value, like `<option value="price">`

Comment: seems no effect 
<select name="orderby">
         <option value="price">Price: $$ - $</option>
         <option value="-price">Price: $ - $$</option></select>

Comment: @boldRichard: the `type="submit"` makes not much sense for an `<option>`.

Comment: @boldRichard: please first remove all these `type="submit"`, and other noise from the form. It looks like the request does *not* visits the page with `?orderby=price` as URL (which is what a GET request should do). See this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select